# Transfer I/O to RAM on ssd based linux

Tags: kubuntu, ssd, ext4, tmpfs

I have kubuntu 20.04 lts on my ext4 installed on ssd. There are processes   **lattedock and jdb2/** constantly writing on ssd.

How can i safely mount these processes on RAM to avoid I/O on ssd, where i have already mounted /var/tmp and /var/log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out from a post that jdb2 manages virtual memory in addition to file journaling from the post
https://partners-intl.aliyun.com/help/en/doc-detail/155605.htm